# Wordpress Insert post create tne meta key and meta value

Tags: wordpress

I am creating wp_insert_post to create post from json, while creating post i need to create meta values i have tried both add_post_meta and update_post_meta no results Can anybody help

foreach ( $response->data as $single_data ) {

```
$post_title    = $single_data->name; 
$video_id = $single_data->uri;
$thumnbnail_url = $single_data->pictures->sizes[4]->link;



if (!post_exists($post_title)) { // Determine if a post exists based on title, content, and date
    $post_id = wp_insert_post(array(
        'post_type'  => 'vimeo_videos',
        'post_title' => $post_title,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
     ));

}
$newPostID = wp_insert_post($post_id);

global $post;

add_post_meta( $post->ID, 'vimeo_video_thumnbnail_url_key', $thumnbnail_url, true );
update_post_meta( $newPostID, 'video_url_id', $video_id );
```

Comment: Are got $newPostID result

Comment: use update_post_meta  to add_post_meta because now only created new post

Answer (score 1):

You're using `wp_insert_post` twice which does not make sense. The first `wp_insert_post` is correct and will return the `$post_id` of the created post upon success. However, your

```
$newPostID = wp_insert_post($post_id);
```

is totally wrong and will always store 0 as a result in `$newPostID`, regardless of whether the post existed beforehand or not since `$post_id` will never contain a valid post array. What you want is to get the ID of the existing post (which `post_exists` already returns if successful). Change your code like so:

```
$existingPostID = post_exists($post_title);
if (!$existingPostID) {
    $existingPostID = wp_insert_post(array(
        'post_type'  => 'vimeo_videos',
        'post_title' => $post_title,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
     ));
}
if ($existingPostID) {
  update_post_meta( $existingPostID, 'video_url_id', $video_id );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For insert new post used this syntax:

add_post_meta( int $post_id, string $meta_key, mixed $meta_value, bool $unique = false )